# What does it mean that the return value __set() is ignore & __get() is never called in chaining assignments?

Tags: php, oop, overloading

I am new to OOP PHP and learning it from [php.net](http://php.net/). There is a **Note** on that page (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) which says that:

> The return value of __set() is ignored because of the way PHP processes the assignment operator. Similarly, __get() is never called when chaining assignments together like this:
>    $a = $obj->b = 8;

It confused me a lot. Can anyone tell what is the point in this note for __set() and __get() magic methods ?

Answer (score 1):

For the statement

```
$a = $obj->b = 8;
```

If $obj->b is being assigned a value using **__set**, or retrieved with **__get**, the assigned value will not be returned for use with $a.

However, if $obj->b is a **public** property and is being directly assigned, the statement will behave as expected, $a will be assigned the same value as the property $b.

Many times, if you are initializing several variables to the same value, you may choose to code it like so:

```
$i = $j = 0;
```

The note is letting you know that you can't do that if you are using **__set** and **__get**.

**__set** and **__get** incur overhead.  Most of the time properties are set and retrieved with explicit set and get functions, such as:

```
public function setB($b) {
   $this->b = $b;
   return $this;
}

public function getB() {
   return $this->b;
}
```

Code which compares several approaches:

```
<?php

// Magic methods to access private properties
Class A {
    private $properties = [];
    public function __set($key,$value) {
        $this->properties[$key] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($key) {
        return isset($this->properties[$key]) ? $this->properties[$key] : null;
    }
}

// Direct access to a public property
Class B {
    public $b;
}

// Set/get access to a private property
// This is the most common approach
Class C {
    private $b;
    public function setB($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function getB() {
        return $this->b;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$c = $a->b = 8;
var_dump($a,$c);

$b = new B();
$c = $b->b = 8;
var_dump($b,$c);

$c = new C();
$c->setB(8);
$d = $c->getB();
var_dump($c,$d);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Property overloading only works in object context. These magic methods will not be triggered in static context. Therefore these methods should not be declared static. As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if one of the magic overloading methods is declared static
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

> Static methods https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php
> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.
> **Caution:** In PHP 5, calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.
> **Warning**: In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated, and will generate an E_DEPRECATED warning. Support for calling non-static methods statically may be removed in the future.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

You can understand the difference between Object & Static context from the links and why php made that caution .

this link will give you an answer for same question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140679/why-is-there-no-facility-to-overload-static-properties-in-php

Moreover have a look at this topic (magic methods)http://culttt.com/2014/04/16/php-magic-methods/